Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH
Windows 7 Python 3.8.10 pip 24.3.1 setuptools 75.3.0 wheel 0.45.1
При попытке установить jupiter notebook в командной строке через: pip install notebook получаю ошибку:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)... error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [6 lines of output]

  Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
  This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
  the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
  
  Checking for Rust toolchain....
  [end of output]

Неужели без установки rust не обойтись. Странно.
При попытке установить более старую версию notebook (7.2.3) получаю идентичный результат.

А установка Rust всё равно не поможет, потому что у вас винда слишком старая

Ну таки попробуйте Rust и менеджер Cargo поставить с https://rustup.rs/ некоторым это помогает. Да, pip с какой-то версии работает на Rust, без него никак.

7.2.3 - это не старая версия, она вышла 5 декабря (как и самая свежая на данный момент 7.3.1). Пробуйте 7.2.2, она вышла 27 августа - до выхода Python 3.13 (и вероятно прекращения поддержки Python 3.8). См. историю версий: https://pypi.org/project/notebook/#history

Очень странно. Я совсем недавно ставил на Windows 11 jupyter notebook, никакой rust не требовался. Может быть вам обновить версию Python? У меня Python3.12 - работает отлично

Глупый вопрос: как установить rust на диск D (в инсталляхе про это нигде не пишет)
Для windows 7 последняя версия python 3.8 (поправьте, если ошибаюсь)

@Polundra да, похоже, Python 3.8 был последним, кто поддерживал Windows 7. То, что какой-то пакет просит Rust означает, что в Pipy нет бинарного пакета для вашей системы. Либо битность не совпадает (например, собран для amd64 а у вас питон 32 бита) либо для Python 3.8 не собирали.

Пробовал версии notebook 7.2.2 и ранее, до 7.1.0 включительно с тем же результатом     Python 64 бита

@Polundra какой пакет требует Rust? Может быть поставить его отдельно? Вот здесь проблема была с y-py, его поставили отдельно без Rust

@Polundra проблема не в версии jupyter, а в версиях пакетов от которых он зависит. Нужно откатывать именно тот пакет, на котором ломается установка

Collecting pywinpty>=2.0.1 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
Using cached pywinpty-2.0.14.tar.gz (27 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

Переустановить питон не пробовали? Или вообще взять какой-то менеджер, например Mamba (Conda)? Пакетные менеджеры могут такие проблемы лучше в каких-то случаях решать.

Выкрутился. Поставил pywinpty 2.0.13 (тк на 2.0.14 падает) и сам notebook 7.2.2  Всем спасибо за помощь

Проблемы с версиями чего угодно обычно решаются docker-ом
